# Updating question - Old answers out of date? What to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I often experience that the first answers to my question bring up important details that do not answer my question, but give important information that takes me another step forward. I then have the problem, that the question itself is not really helpful anymore, cause I would reask it in another way (from my new viewpoint).

What should I do then?
Just edit an "Update" into the question and ask the new, revisioned question? This would let the answers look wrong or outdated.
Another option would be to remove the whole question and reask it with my new knowledge. But besides I do not know if this is possible, this would remove every answer too.

Hope this question is asked clearly and I do not have to reask it :)

**UPDATE:**
So I think the way is to update the question and point out the new point of view and perhaps an updated (more precise/slightly corrected) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an answer takes you a step forward but you have a new problem, then create a new question. If it makes sense include a link back to the original question.  *(Example: your question was about how to get a SQL query running from Java and an answer get you connected and running, but now you have a SQLException)*

If an answer changes your perspective on the question, then as squilman suggests, add an update to your question and make it clear that you have updated it.  *(Example: your question was about how to solve a SQLException and an answer points out that you are not catching it correctly and don't have all the correct details)*

In all cases I would not remove the question because it could be useful to someone else and in fact it was a question you did have moments before.

Comment: Think thats the way to go

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about answers becoming obsolete then add updates to the bottom of your question.  Make it clear that the updates are not part of the original question and also clearly address anyone who you are responding to in your updates.  This will also allow people to see the entire history more plainly and be able to judge whether or not they have something new to add.  Keep in mind, though, that the sites are not discussion sites :)