# your old upvoted/accepted answers, what to do about them?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, obsolete-information

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

This was already asked from [question poster's side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76886/updating-question-old-answers-out-of-date-what-to-do), but what about answer posters side? I've have had recently received down-votes on answers that were correct, up-voted and even accepted two years ago ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671057/firefox-addon-to-remove-cache-and-cookies-of-one-domain/671112#671112)). Now they are outdated, sometimes even not correct in current circumstances. So what should I do about them? I have way over thousand answers on SO and other SE sites, so reviewing all of them is out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't do a blanket review, but if you get feedback on an individual post, maybe check it is still valid. Otherwise, the time logged against your answer should qualify that it was posted *at a particular point in time*, and the reader should be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Well I like jzd's answer in the posting you linked to from the "Question poster's side". I think the answer should be clearly updated to say how it would work in today's world, if you know the answer. If you don't know how to make it work in today's envionment, make it clear that this answer only applies for a particular dated environment and it no longer works in the current environment.

If, for some reason, it no longer works **at all**, even for the environment that it was originally answered for, then either state that or consider deleting the answer at that point.

If you have so many answer that you can't review them all, so be it. Either the question is obsolete and nobody cares that the is obsolete too, or someone else will review it for you and down vote it. At which point, you can make a decision on what to do with the answer.

That's my two-cents.